# Database Administrators Top User Swag

Tags: discussion

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://dba.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Database Administrators t-shirt in your size
- Database Administrators die-cut, vinyl stickers
- Stack Exchange sharpie
- Stack Exchange pen
- Stack Exchange stickers

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: dba.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### The sticker

[image: dba.stackexchange.com sticker]

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- unfortunately we aren't able to gift this swag to everybody, but it will be available for sponsored events as needed)</sub>

Comment: missed out by a little over a page... :-(

Comment: Better keep my numbers up before I fall off page 2...

Comment: Thank you, DBA.SE !!!

Comment: What about moderators business cards? ;-)

Comment: Awesome, free t-shirts are always good!!!

Comment: Wow! Thanks DBA.SE! Who doesn't love swag?

Comment: @jcolebrand 6-8 weeks for the design... ;)

Comment: Cool! That's a nice gift! Though we should thank you too...somehow.

Comment: @Marian the best way to thank us is to continue being awesome on the site :)

Comment: Thank you! I can't wait to wear it.

Comment: So, in the future, when ever I am sad, I'll go on dba.SE and just be more awesome instead. [Barney](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barney_Stinson) would do that! :)

Comment: @garik I don't quite understand your statement. our UX users have received their top user packages a while back. Were you supposed to receive one and didn't?

Comment: Simple and elegant... Thank you :-)

Comment: @garik Sorry to hear that. We'll resend you another UX package. Although we can't guarantee if it will get to you for sure since once the package leaves our warehouse it's at the mercy of your postal system. We've had a lot of problems with certain countries in the past.

Comment: Great swag. I'll be happy to wear it and geek out.

Comment: Only shirt other than DBA.SE to wear : http://www.thinkgeek.com/tshirts-apparel/595d/

Comment: @Jin. Today I got the UX gift. Thank you for your personal help!

Comment: When will the top DBA.SE users be receiving this email?  I haven't received the email yet.

Comment: @AnnaLear Unfortunately I did not receive this email.  Can it be resent to me?  Thank you!

Comment: @AnnaLear Nevermind, I did receive the email.  I just submitted the form.  I look forward to the shirt!!  Thank you!

Comment: Very nice, thank you :)

Comment: Will we be seeing our swag packages sometime in mid-September ???

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Possibly? They should be shipping out shortly.

Comment: Thank You, @AnnaLear !!!

Comment: I just got my package today. Thank you !!!

Comment: Thanks for the package, just got it yesterday!

Comment: Thank you, guys! My package just arrived this morning! Way faster than expected :-). Now I need to start the payback part, because I feel I deserve only one sleeve of the t-shirt for the last months work :D.

Comment: Just received mine. Many thanks!

Comment: I never did say thank you for this when I got it this summer. So thank you @AnnaLear and Stack exchange! I've worn my shirt more than a few times. Now I need to start sticking around here more regularly.

Comment: @AnnaLear Can I send another kitten for a dba sticker?

Comment: @AnnaLear Is this going to be this year ?

Comment: @Kin No, we only do this once per site.

Comment: @AnnaLear unfortunately, I joined this year .. being active on this site .. thanks for your response though !

Comment: @AnnaLear sad!!

Comment: Oh god, want so bad!